# How can I smooth a curve to ease the reading?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I am trying to smooth curves to ease the reading of spikes in a graph, when I tried to import savgol_filter from Scipy packsaage, but it doesn't look that it works.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x) + np.random.random(100) * 0.2
yhat = savitzky_golay(y, 51, 3) # window size 51, polynomial order 3

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,yhat, color='red')
plt.show()


from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name savgol_filter
```

I am thinking about using Linear Regression to do that, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `savgol_filter` was added to scipy in version 0.14.0.  What version are you using?   You can check by running `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: By the way, you import `savgol_filter`, but later you use `savitzy_golay`.  Once you get the import working (probably by installing a new scipy), you'll need to fix that, too.